# Adding tabs from different classes into main

Tags: java, class, tabs, program-entry-point

I'm creating an application with four different tabs. Instead of putting the code for all four tabs in one class I chose to put each tab in a different class. Now I'm having trouble trying to integrate the tabs into one window in the applications main class. What is the best way to go about doing this? Here is an example of one of the classes which contains the code for one tab, simplified, the others are relatively the same. The classes work fine on their own. Any suggestions would be much appreciated...

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class calculate extends JFrame{
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    public calculate () {

        //GridBag Constraints
        GridBagConstraints grid = new GridBagConstraints();
        grid.fill = GridBagConstraints.BOTH;
        grid.anchor = GridBagConstraints.NORTH;


        //Create panel add components
        JPanel p2 = new JPanel(new GridBagLayout());

        JLabel floorOp = new JLabel("SELECT FLOORING OPTION", SwingConstants.CENTER);
        grid.gridx = 0;
        grid.gridy = 0;
        grid.gridwidth = 2;
        grid.ipady = 10;
        grid.ipadx = 40;
        floorOp.setOpaque(true);
        floorOp.setBackground(Color.decode("#CCFFFF"));
        floorOp.setBorder(BorderFactory.createMatteBorder(3, 0, 1, 0, Color.lightGray));
        p2.add(floorOp, grid);

        ButtonGroup groupBtn = new ButtonGroup();
        JRadioButton smallBtn = new JRadioButton("Hard Wood");
        groupBtn.add(smallBtn);
        grid.gridx = 0;
        grid.gridy = 1;
        grid.gridwidth = 1;
        grid.ipady = 10;
        smallBtn.setOpaque(true);
        smallBtn.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
        smallBtn.setHorizontalAlignment(AbstractButton.CENTER);
        p2.add(smallBtn, grid);

        JRadioButton mediumBtn = new JRadioButton("Carpet");
        groupBtn.add(mediumBtn);
        grid.gridx = 1;
        grid.gridy = 1;
        mediumBtn.setOpaque(true);
        mediumBtn.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
        mediumBtn.setHorizontalAlignment(AbstractButton.CENTER);
        p2.add(mediumBtn, grid);

        JLabel space = new JLabel("");
        grid.gridx = 0;
        grid.gridy = 2;
        grid.ipady = 25;
        p2.add(space, grid);

        JLabel dims = new JLabel("ENTER DIMENSIONS", SwingConstants.CENTER);
        grid.gridx = 0;
        grid.gridy = 3;
        grid.gridwidth = 2;
        grid.ipady = 10;
        grid.ipadx = 40;
        dims.setOpaque(true);
        dims.setBackground(Color.decode("#CCFFFF"));
        dims.setBorder(BorderFactory.createMatteBorder(3, 0, 1, 0, Color.lightGray));
        p2.add(dims, grid);

        JLabel length = new JLabel("Length:", SwingConstants.CENTER);
        grid.gridx = 0;
        grid.gridy = 4;
        grid.gridwidth = 1;
        length.setOpaque(true);
        length.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
        p2.add(length, grid);

        JTextField lengthTxt = new JTextField(20);
        grid.gridx = 1;
        grid.gridy = 4;
        p2.add(lengthTxt, grid);

        JLabel width = new JLabel("Width:", SwingConstants.CENTER);
        grid.gridx = 0;
        grid.gridy = 5;
        width.setOpaque(true);
        width.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
        p2.add(width, grid);

        JTextField widthTxt = new JTextField(20);
        grid.gridx = 1;
        grid.gridy = 5;
        p2.add(widthTxt, grid);

    }
}
```

This is what I thought I should do in my main but it's throwing exceptions

```
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JTabbedPane;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;

public class appMain {
JFrame frame = new JFrame();
JTabbedPane tabbedPane = new JTabbedPane();
selectTab fp = new selectTab();
calculate sp = new calculate();

public appMain() {
    tabbedPane.add("First", fp);
    tabbedPane.add("Second", sp);
    frame.getContentPane().add(tabbedPane);
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.setSize(640, 480);
    // frame.pack();
    frame.setLocationByPlatform(true);
    frame.setVisible(true);
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            new appMain();
        }
    });
}

}
```